# Receiving WebRTC call from a C++ native Windows application

Tags: c++, windows, webrtc

I would like, from a native Windows application using C++, to receive video/audio data sent from a browser located in a remote location.  It seems like WebRTC is the way to go for this.

Most information I find is about how to interact with the browser to write WebRTC apps, but it may case the data would be received by my C++ app.  Is it correct that I would need to use the WebRTC Native Code package for this, which is described as being 'for browser developers'?  Document is located here: http://www.webrtc.org/webrtc-native-code-package

And what if I want to send video/audio data that I generate (ie not directly coming from a webcam and microphone), would I be able to send it to the remote location browser?

Any sample code out there which does something like I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

The wording in that link is a bit misleading. They intend people that are developing browsers to use the native code, and advise those that are developing "applications" in a browser to use the [WebRTC API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html).

I have worked with [their native code](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/) for over a year to develop an Android application that is capable of performing audio and / or video calls between other Android devices and to browsers. So, I a pretty sure that it is completely possible to to take their native code and create a Windows application (especially since they have example code that does that for Linux and Mac -- look at peerconnection client and peerconnection server for this). You might have to write and re-write code to get it to work on Windows.

As for as data that you generate. In the Android project that I worked with, we didn't rely on the Android device / system to provide us with video, we captured and sent that out our selves using the "LibJingle" / WebRTC libraries. So, I know that that is possible, as long as you provide the libraries with video data in the correct format. I would imagine that one would be able to do the same with audio, but we never fiddled with that, so I cannot say for sure.

And as for example code, I can only suggest [Luke Weber's gitbug repositories](https://github.com/lukeweber). Although it is for Android, it might be of some help to look at how he interfaces with the two libraries. Probably the better code to look at is the peerconnection client stuff that comes in the "LibJingle" second of the native code. [edit]: That is located in /talk/examples/peerconection/client/ .

If you get lost from my use of "LibJingle", that will show you when I started working with all of this code. Sometime around July of 2013 they migrated "LibJingle" into the WebRTC "talk" folder. From everything that I have seen, they are the same thing, just with the location and named changed.